# Apply aggregates function on count / group by on multiple tables

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I Have 2 tables

table1 (sailors):

```
id_sailor   name 
1       Barondeau   
2       Vighetti
```

table2 (voyages):

```
id_ voyage     boat       id_sailor
1                Juliette         1
2                Juliette         1
3               La belle          2
4               La Belle          1
```

How can I make this new table :

n is the number of voyages for a sailor on a specific boat –

```
   boat     name      n     
   Juliette Barondeau 2
   La Belle Barondeau 1
   La Belle Vighetti  1
```

What I tried :

```
  select "table2"."boat", "table1"."name", count("table2"."boat" ) as "n"
  from "table1", "table2" 
  where "table1"."id_sailor" = "table2"."id_sailor"
  group by "table2"."name"
  ;
```

In hsqldb 1.8, I have  this error "Not in aggregate function or group by clause : 1b6128f..."

Comment: n is the number of voyages for a sailor on a specific boat

Comment: ok @Wilcar got it

Comment: On a sidenote: You should have a separate table for boats. Otherwiese a simple typo like  `'La belle'` vs. ' La Belle'` in your sample data can already lead to wrong results.

Comment: As to `GROUP BY`: `GROUP BY xyz` means one result row per xyz. So if you want one result row per boat and sailor you must group by boat and sailor.

Comment: @Wilcar You need to mark the answer accepted. If you have any concerns with answer. Then, let them know. This is totally disrespect to people who are helping you.

Comment: I am still working on it

Comment: @Wilcar You need to let us know. This isn't how StackOverflow work

Comment: @Wilcar Also, did you used what I proposed solution ? I don't think so. You need to be clear with your question.

Comment: Ok, I understanded my mistake combining the two answers. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `group by "table2"."boat"` in your `GROUP BY` clause remaining looks fine.

```
 group by "table2"."boat","table2"."name"
```

instead of

```
group by "table2"."name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Appears to simple "group by" based query

```
select
      v.boat, s.name, count(*) n
from voyages v
innner join sailors s on v.id_sailor = s.id_sailor   
group by
      v.boat, s.name
```

The important point to note here is that ALL selected columns NOT USING aggregate functions *{such as COUNT(*)}* should be listed in the group by clause.

Comment: I am not very experienced

Comment: Ok, you help me to find my mistakes

Comment: extremely young? or just not very experienced with SQL? :)

Answer (score 1):

just need to add group by table2.boat.

```
select table2.boat, table1.name, count(table2.boat) as n
from table1, table2 
where table1.id_sailor = table2.id_sailor
group by table1.name , table2.boat;
```